# How can I refer to another control in a XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reference, controls

I'm working in a C# WPF application, based on XAML files.

I have a label, called "Label_Productnaam".

I would like to create another control (a `ComboBox`), having the same height.

Therefore I'm trying something like this:

```
<Label Content="Productnaam :" Name="Label_Productnaam"></Label>
...
<ComboBox ... Height="{Binding "Label_Productnaam.Height"}"
```

This, however, seems not to work.

What's the easiest way to say in a XAML that the height of my combobox must be the same as the one of the referred label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind to the property, and then specify the other element by name.  Here it would be:

```
<ComboBox Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Label_Productnaam}"/>
```